# embedded google map not showing complete map until resize window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm having problems with the google map I'm  embeding, don't understand why on load the  map appears to be very small sized  and only corrects its size when I resize the window, then instantly  the map is shown the way its supposed to, It seems as  if  it needs to be repainted, and  I know  this is  not necessary, what is the problem ? here is the link to the page,  the map is  inside a div,  its  at the bottom of the page and the div's background is black,  it is called  `Donde Trabajamos`  please click it and see for yourselves,  what  is going wrong ?

www.plastinemor.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post some code.. but try this:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.panTo(Marker1.getPosition());
});
```

Comment: Hello,  well the thing  is that the code is very long so probly get bad comments or rating.